# Pip3 Install Wordcloud error: can't build wheels

Tags: python, word-cloud

I tried installing wordcloud. I have python 3.10, mac ventura 13.4.1. I tried installing wheels as well, butwasn't sure what version, and nothing worked either. can anyone help me get this up and running? Has anyone encountered the same?

````
Collecting wordcloud
  Using cached wordcloud-1.9.2.tar.gz (222 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from wordcloud) (1.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from wordcloud) (10.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from wordcloud) (3.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (4.41.0)
```Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing<3.1,>=2.3.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: wordcloud
  Building wheel for wordcloud (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for wordcloud (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/wordcloud_cli.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/tokenization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/wordcloud.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/color_from_image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/stopwords -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/DroidSansMono.ttf -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      UPDATING build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud/_version.py
      set build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud/_version.py to '1.9.2'
      running build_ext
      building 'wordcloud.query_integral_image' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c wordcloud/query_integral_image.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/wordcloud/query_integral_image.o
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wordcloud
Failed to build wordcloud
ERROR: Could not build wheels for wordcloud, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects```
````

Comment: Try `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error before when I tried to install Pillow, and when I searched about it, I realized this error is from the OS. I changed my OS (I just reinstalled another Windows version), and the problem was solved.

But you can also try anaconda (or miniconda, maybe).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i try to install hecdsstools, three main things are two for the issue.

1. Operating system version not compatible, because wheel files were run in specific os only go through the notes of developer of wheel file, provide your os version and ask for the required wheel.
2. Python version, in specific python version only libraries install the correct version as per developer notes.